# ggplot2 - how to scale two y-axes

Tags: ggplot2

————————SOLVED

I have the following data:

```
my_data <- data.frame(
  th = c(1.2, 1.0, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.01),
  ob = c(40, 34, 15, 11, 11, 12, 13, 16),
  ski = c(3000, 2509, 1309, 1209, 4322, 1283, 383, 245)
)
```

I want to plot the data with x-axis = `th`, left y-axis = `ob` and right y-axis = `ski`.

I do not know how to set accurate axes labels and limits, because in my example the blue line representing `ski` has missing values with the following error:

`Removed 8 rows containing missing values (`geom_line()`).`

I tried the following:

```
p <- ggplot(my_data, aes(x = th)) 
p <- p +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 1.2, by = 0.2),
    limits = c(1.2, 0),
    trans = "reverse" 
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "ob",
    breaks = seq(0, 50, by = 10),
    limits = c(0, 50),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 60, name = "ski")
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(y = ob), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = ski), color = "blue")
print(p)
```

The left y-axis should be from 0 to 50 and the right y-axis from 0 to 5000.
How to solve that issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For your code in the question, there is only one set of y-axis values at play, specified as `limits = c(0, 50)`. The secondary axis is meant mostly for transformations of the same type of measurement (e.g. miles on one axis and kilometers on the other axis). In your plot, `ski` is being plotted against the left y-axis. The right axis is essentially a cosmetic change to the left. If you expand your limits, the `ski` line will appear way up above.

Comment: You can do the scaling hack as seen in your answer, but the problem is that you can adjust this factor to make the lines appear wherever you like vertically. You must be careful not to draw unwanted interpretations.

This answer to another question brings up great points about the flaws with multiple y-axes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales/3101876#3101876

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. I specified a coefficient:

```
coeff <- 100
```

used it in the `sec.axis` and then divided `ski` by the `coeff` in the `geom_line` as follows:

```
p <- ggplot(my_data, aes(x = th)) 
p <- p +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 1.2, by = 0.2),
    limits = c(1.2, 0),
    trans = "reverse" 
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "ob",
    breaks = seq(0, 50, by = 10),
    limits = c(0, 50),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * coeff, name = "ski")
  ) +
  geom_line(aes(y = ob), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = ski / coeff), color = "blue")
print(p)
```